# How to set Power and Sleep settings?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I'd like to change Screen & Sleep time to `Never` from code. I'm seeing code that prevents the Screen Saver from executing, but don't see anything for Screen & Sleep timers.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: To what end? If this is "whilst my application is doing X, the system should stay available", be aware that changing the machine settings is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The machine will be used as a kiosk. Therefore, the installer needs to set this value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the [Powercfg utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options).

Here are some useful options *(xx = minutes)*:

- Timeout to turn off the display (plugged in): `monitor-timeout-ac xx`.
- Timeout to turn off the display (battery): `monitor-timeout-dc xx`.
- Timeout to go to sleep (plugged in): `standby-timeout-ac xx`.
- Timeout to go to sleep (battery): `standby-timeout-dc xx`.
- Timeout to go into hibernate (plugged in): `hibernate-timeout-ac xx`.
- Timeout to go into hibernate (battery): `hibernate-timeout-dc xx`.

**Full example:**

```
// Set the monitor timout to "never".
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C powercfg /change -monitor-timeout-ac 0");
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
```

Alternatively, you may use WMI to achieve the same goal. Here are some related posts:

- [Get value of Sleep After/Hibernate After from advanced power settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49727980/8967612)
- [setting power options from code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7457000/8967612)
- [Programmatically change Windows power settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3802301/8967612).